# How to use a ZTE MF 190 dongle in Ubuntu

Tags: usb-modem, zte

How can I use a ZTE MF 190 USB dongle in Ubuntu 12.10? The connection manager in the device memory runs only in Windows. Is there a connection manager for Ubuntu? Please help!

Answer (score -1):

try may it can work with you I try it work with other too

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2178349

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.